# A non well formed numeric value encountered Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am facing an error in laravel 5.2

> ErrorException in Helpers.php line 616:
>       A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: C:\laragon\www\trunqd-dev\resources\views\post\postCard.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\trunqd-dev\resources\views\post\postCard.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\trunqd-dev\resources\views\post\postCard.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\trunqd-dev\resources\views\post\postCard.blade.php)

my helpers.php

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  $width
 * @param  $height
 * @param  get Image ratio
 * @return Response
 */
function imageRatio($width, $height, $flag = 0, $fixWidth = 218)
{
    $n_width = $width > $fixWidth ? $fixWidth : $width;
    if(!empty($height) && !empty($width)){
        $n_height = floor(($height/$width)*$n_width);
        if ($flag == 2) {
            $n_height = floor($n_width * 9) / 16;
        }
    }else{
        $n_height = 160;
    }

    if($flag == 1){
        return array('width' => $n_width, 'height' => $n_height);
    } 

    return "width:" . $n_width . "px;height:" . $n_height . "px;";
}
```

I am using php 7.0. Please assist I don't know why I am facing this error.

Comment: The issue is with your `postCard.blade.php`. Please post the content of this file.